# for loop in bash/python to break a large string to mutiple strings

Tags: python, bash

How to separate a large string in to a multiple strings

```
a1=1234567891122334455667788
```

I want to break `a1` string as multiple strings as following

```
a2=123   
a3=456   
a4=789    
a5=112
```

like the same for rest of the string value

I tried with the `for` loop but couldn't get the expected result.
I used `if` statement in `for` loop to break the loop once the 3 values added in to a string `a2` and so but I finding difficult to store the 3 values each time to add in increment variable `a+` (`a2 a3 a4`)

Comment: Do you need/want to specifically use a loop?

Comment: not like that , anything is fine. I thought it will be done with for loop,

Comment: every 3 characters as a string ?

Comment: @SandeepLade: yes .. every 3 characters with separate string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not slicing, the problem is how to store the sliced values in variables. I suggest you to use `dict` so that you can use it as key, value pair.

```
a1 = '1234567891122334455667788'

d = {} ; c=2
for i in range(0,len(a1),3):
    d['a'+str(c)] = a1[i:i+3] 
    c+=1

print(d)

{'a8': '566', 'a10': '8', 'a4': '789', 'a9': '778', 'a6': '233', 'a7': '445', 'a3': '456', 'a5': '112', 'a2': '123'}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [more-itertools'](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.sliced) `sliced()` to slice the string into equal chunks:

```
>>> import more_itertools
>>> a1 = '1234567891122334455667788'
>>> list(more_itertools.sliced(a1, 3))
['123', '456', '789', '112', '233', '445', '566', '778', '8']
```

Comment: cool.. looks that not a built-in module with python package. I'll download and try that .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach could be to slice the string in chunks of 3 characters

```
 s = "1234567891122334455667788"
 while i < len(s):
    print(s[i:i+3])
    i += 3
```

Comment: yes this is also giving my expected result .. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use list comprehension like this:

```
a = [a1[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a1), 3)]
```

Now how to get the actual indices to the variables `a1`, `a2`, .. , `an`. That's another problem I don't have an answer to.

Looking at your accepted answer you could also use dict comprehension:

```
d = {'a'+str(i/3+2): a1[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(a1), 3)}
```

But this is quite possibly harder to read.

Comment: I'm happy with the comprehension answer "a"

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    >>> a1='1234567891122334455667788'
>>> itr=1
>>> a2=""
>>> lst=[]
>>> for i in a1:
    #print a2
    a2=a2+str(i)
    if (itr%3==0):
        lst.append(a2)
        itr=0
        a2=''
    itr+=1
```

Output will be

```
  >>> lst
['123', '456', '789', '112', '233', '445', '566', '778']
```

Comment: @DasD : I changed my answer to store in a list. If the answer is useful mark it as useful